# Python- creating a text file with a variable as a name

Tags: python, text-files, filenames

So im doing a project where my program creates a textfile named "Ten Green Bottles" and writes the 10 green bottles song in it, I have successfully got it working but i want to make it better. I started by making the amount of bottles optional to the user and it worked fine. Now i just want the name to be relevent with the amount of bottles input by the user. ie, if I put in 20 bottles i want the name of the text file to be "Twenty Green Bottles" rather than "Ten Green Bottles"
Code:

```
num1=int(input('Pick a number between 10 and 30: '))

def main():
    numbers =[ 'no', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven',      'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen',     'Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen', 'Nineteen', 'Twenty', 'Twentyone',      'Twentytwo', 'Twentythree', 'Twentyfour', 'Twentyfive', 'Twentysix',         'Twentyseven', 'Twentyeight', 'Twentynine', 'Thirty' ]
text_one = 'green bottle%s\nHanging on the wall'
text_two = "\nAnd if one green bottle\nShould accidentally fall\nThere'll be"
text_three =' \n'


with open( 'Green Bottles.txt', 'w') as a:
    for l in range(num1, 0, -1):
        a.write(numbers[l]+ ' ')
        if l == 1:
            a.write(text_one % '' +'\n')
        else:
            a.write(text_one % 's' +'\n')

        a.write(numbers[l] + ' ')
        if l == 1:
            a.write(text_one %  '' + '\n') 
        else:
            a.write(text_one % 's' +  '\n')
        a.write(text_two + ' ')
        a.write(numbers[l-1] + ' ')
        if (l - 1) ==1 :
            a.write(text_one % ''+'\n')
        else:
            a.write(text_one % 's'+'\n')
        a.write('\n' + '\n')



if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: just note; line 5,6,7 are indented properly on my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
with open( 'Green Bottles.txt', 'w') as a:
```

With

```
with open(numbers[num1] + ' Green Bottles.txt', 'w') as a:
```

This will prepend your file name with the appropriate word.

Answer (score 2):

You could give the name of the file to a function and return the file.

```
def write(nameOfFile):
    print('Creating new text file') 

    name = nameOfFile+'.txt'  # Name of text file coerced with +.txt

    try:
        file = open(name,'r+')   # Trying to create a new file or open one
        return file

    except:
        print('Something went wrong! Can\'t tell what?')
        sys.exit(0) # quit Python

a = write(numbers[num1] )
```

Comment: Just a point on your suggested edit on my post. Note that index `1` for `numbers` is "One". There is no need for the `-1`

Comment: Yeah, sorry didn't notice that

Answer (score 1):

You can add your input to file name using string format

use

```
with open('%s Green Bottles.txt' % numbers[num1], 'w') as a:
```

Comment: Your `%d` should probably be a `%s` :)

Comment: @Loocid thanks for correction :), Input is integer so that was in my mind ;)